# Replacing binary mode file object for urllib2

Tags: python, google-app-engine, curl, urllib2, urllib

I have a piece of code that looks like this, and it works as is in local (without using any AppEngine):

```
bodyParams = { "file" : open( filePath, "rb" )  }
request = urllib2.Request( requestUrl, None, self.buildAuthInfo() )
response = self.getOpener().open(request, bodyParams).read()
```

I would like to get rid of `open`, i.e `open( filePath, "rb" )` , because in Google AppEngine working with files is prohibited (or really inconvenient).

In order to solve the problem, I get a HTTP POST data of a base64 encoded image file, I decode it. I send the encoded data via cURL, using the following command:

```
curl -X POST -F image=@encoded http://localhost:8080/image-process
```

`encoded` is a base64 encoded jpg.

At this point, I tried two different things: putting the decoded data into a `StringIO` object, or directly passing and using inside `bodyParams = { "file" : DECODEDVALUE}`. I would expect either of these to work, but I get a HTTP 500 error from the target server (where I'm doing an external API request). This is how I decode the value:

```
img = self.request.get('image')
DECODEDVALUE = MyStringIO(base64.b64decode(img))
```

I believe I have a problem related to encoding and/or binary mode. I believe I have a problem related to encoding and/or binary mode.

How can I get rid of `open` and the use of file objects, in favor of `StringIO`, `BytesIO`, or `str` objects?

---

NOTE: just for clarity, not related to the original problem. `MyStringIO` is a subclass of `StringIO.StringIO` with `__len__` added:

```
class MyStringIO(StringIO.StringIO):
  def __len__(self):
    return self.len
```

---

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, and it seems like you're asking multiple questions. Could you edit your post to include exactly one question, what you are trying, and the error you are getting (or inability to find some solution)? This would help us.

Comment: I edited the solution a bit, to make it more clear. Does it look more understandable now? Thanks

Comment: I think you should use BytesIO

Comment: Is the file uploaded by a user? What do you do with the file after they upload it?

Comment: Opening files on App Engine is perfectly fine - it's just writing to them that's prohibited. I second mjibson's comment that it's not clear what you're asking. Also, telling us you "get a 500" is uninformative. A 500 is what a server returns when something goes wrong internally, and it usually either includes extra information, or the server logs it somewhere. Where are the details?